# Understanding the difference between EMC ECS and EMC ScaleIO

Tags: cloud, storage, emc

As per my understanding **EMC ECS and ScaleIO** applications are used for combining all the drives of the **storage nodes** in **Data Center** to form a pool of resources. I have googled out to find out more information on the similarities and differences b/w these two,but not able to get much info.

Looking for more info on, what are the differences in these products and what are the use cases for these applications ? Are these tools fall under the same category to compare and for what purpose these tools are serving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two storage products solve different problems. I'll put it in very simple terms:

ScaleIO is block-level storage. Every host in a cluster can function as both a compute and storage node. The nodes have direct attached storage. ScaleIO is installed on each host and pools the storage resources. It's a distributed and scale-out storage architecture. This type of storage is needed when running high performant applications that need high availability such as general applications and databases.

ECS (Elastic Cloud Storage) is object based storage. It's analogous to running Amazon S3 on premise. So if you're application uses object storage to get media such as JPG/MOV/MPEG/DOC/XLS type of files, then this is what you want to use.

Comment: Can I say both differs in the way it stores the data, like **ScaleIO** as **block-level** and **ECS** as **object-based** ?? One more confusion, I know that **ECS** pools only resources of a **Storage node**, does **ScaleIO** pools resources of both **compute** and **storage node** in a data center ??

Comment: you're correct in your assumption of how each store data. AFAIK, ECS will not pool storage across nodes in the downloadable version. I've never tried. However, ScaleIO will pool both compute and storage across nodes in the free downloadable version. ECS can also be sold as an appliance for on-prem.

Comment: That confuses me either. I don’t get what exact purpose do ECS, ScaleIO and vSAN have since all of these products belong to the same company now.

Comment: **ECS** – blob cold storage. **SIO** – generic multi-tenant storage. **VMware vSAN** http://www.vmware.com/ru/products/virtual-san.html is a good VM storage, but it's for vSphere only. **StarWind VSAN** https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san is another good option, it was even developed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words.
ECS is a like a private AWS in a hardware box.(Object Storage)
ScaleIO is like Hadoop for Block Storage .(Distributed Object storage)